# Gas stove burner

Tags: stove, gas

My burners click all the time while the burners are on. They only stop when I turn the flames off. How do I stop them from clicking while the flame is on?

Comment: What sort of stove do you have? Are you leaving the burners in "light" mode? The clicking is generally the flint striking to light the gas and should stop once you're not in the "light" setting but different stoves light in different ways, which is why knowing what sort of stove you have is helpful.

Comment: It's an Electrolux ICON. Yes, I am turning the dial to medium flame, but it still clicks.

Comment: Sounds like a failure in the controls; if it's still under warranty you should file a claim.

Comment: My wolf cooktop does that when it's wet or dirty.

Answer (score 2):

The spark igniter on a typical gas stove that replaces the pilot light of older stoves should stop once the stove is lit. Two reasons off the top of my head that this could malfunction.

1. It's wet or dirty. Moisture/dirt can interfere with the spark igniter. Make sure you clean the igniter and the stove and burner around the igniter well. This might require a bit of disassembly if you spilled a lot into there. You might need to use some sort of degreaser to get the thing properly clean. Let it dry completely before trying again.
2. It's broken. There are a couple parts that could cause a problem. I'd contact warranty/service if you're sure it's clean and dry and it still occurs (and you're not comfortable debugging the electronics yourself).

Answer (score 0):

My stove (european) has two pins next to the burner head. One is the spark igniter and one is a temperature sensor.
My stove runs the igniter until the heat of the flame has heatet up the temperature sensor enough (also it will turn of the gas if the temperature sensor gets cold for some amunt of time. That#s for security reasons to prevent gas spills).

If your stove has temperature sensors, try to clean both pins and the burner head. It might also help to take apart the loose components of the head and reassemble them carefully (i have trouble igniting my stove if the lid isn't perfectly plain on the head).

Another (rare) problem at our home is: we spread tin foil on the bottom to ease cleaning (saw that in professional kitchens). Sometimes the cutout for the burners aren't clean enough and a piece of tinfoil comes near the igniter and prevents the igniter to spark towards the burner head.